# I am having trouble retrieving the data using the resolver with @graphql-tools/load-files

Tags: javascript, graphql

I can't use loadfiles method to get the resolver data, which will return null, but I can get it through 'import Resolver from "./lists/utensils.resolvers.mjs";'.

Here is my server.js file

```
import express from "express";
    import { graphqlHTTP } from "express-graphql";
    import { makeExecutableSchema } from "@graphql-tools/schema";
    import { loadFilesSync, loadFiles } from "@graphql-tools/load-files";
    
    async function loadResolvers() {
      return await loadFiles("**/*resolvers.mjs", {
        extensions: ["mjs"],
      });
    }
    
    async function startGraphQLServer() {
      try {
   
        const typesArray = loadFilesSync("**/*", { extensions: ["graphql"] });
    
        const resolverArray = await loadResolvers();
    
       
        const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
          typeDefs: typesArray,
          resolvers: resolverArray,
        });
    
        const app = express();
        app.use("/graphql", graphqlHTTP({ schema: schema, graphiql: true }));
        app.listen(3000, () => {
          console.log("Running GraphQL server");
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error starting GraphQL server:", error);
      }
    }
    
    startGraphQLServer();
```

and this resolver.mjs file.

```
import getAll from "./utensils.model.mjs";

const utensilsModel = {
  Query: {
    products: async () => {
      try {
        return await getAll ();
      } catch {
        console.error(error);
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch utensils");
      }
    },
  },
};

export default utensilsModel ;
```